# Mirth originalFilename rename

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, mirth

I have been trying to remove .dat from ${originalFilename} in destination when i tried to do this ${originalFilename}.txt it gave me like 1652807798759.dat.txt how can i get **1652807798759.txt** only without .dat in it

**I have tried to do this in Destination's Transformer but no luck**

```
channelMap.put('OrigFilename', sourceMap.get('originalFilename'));

var outFile = channelMap.get('OrigFilename');
logger.info('outFile ' + outFile ); // i am getting outFile as null here
//outFile=outFile.replace('.dat','');
```

Comment: Is this java or javascript? There's a major difference. You're using javascript syntax but it looks like that's a java Map...

Comment: It is actually Mirth connect tool which uses java and javascript

Comment: @Pew - Mirth Connect uses the Rhino project (https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) and it commingles both JavaScript and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace should work:

```
//test it with a static string first, in real code use sourceMap.get('originalFilename').toString();
var outFile = '1652807798759.dat.txt' ; 
outFile = outFile.replace(/\.dat/g, "");
logger.info('outFile ' + outFile );
```